# Shiurim on Approaches of Meforshim

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, product-recommendation, rabbis, internet, adult-learning

Does anyone know of any good shiurim that I could find online that go through the approaches of the various meforshim on Torah?

Answer (score 3):

Amazing website with exactly what you are looking for:

https://etzion.org.il/en/series/great-biblical-commentators-en

Answer (score 2):

This particular website has Shiurim about the Approach of the RAMBAM and Ramban
[HashkafaCircle](http://hashkafacircle.com/shiurim/)